# Nested traversals vs Separate Interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

For typescript we are having a conversation as to which is better and I was wondering if there was any consensus or insight into the variations.

Taking this as an example:

```
interface Product {
  ...
}

export interface Factory {
  product: Product[];
}
```

If we wanted to access the `Product` type elsewhere in the code is it better to use:

1) **Nested Traversal**

```
Factory['product'][0]
```

to make it clear that the product is a child of the Factory.

or

2) **Separate interfaces**

export `Product` from the example above and use it independently

```
Product
```

to make the code cleaner.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: What do you mind by "export Property" ?

Comment: Change the example to: `export interface Product { ... }` and then import the `Product` interface directly

Comment: I realized I had a typo in the original question and I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

First, note that it may be safer to replace `Factory['product'][0]` by `Factory['product'][number]`. In your case it changes nothing, but if someday you use an array with specific type for indexes you can have type errors.

--

Nested traversal is quite usefull when you want to say to devs that field type is **from this type** (Factory in your case).

- Good: declarative, create a symbolic link between the two types (Product and Factory).
- Bad: when I see `Factory['product'][0]` I have to go to Factory type to see what is the real type behind.

There is not a "best way to do", just keep in mind your type declaration must be understable, don't use nested traversal if it doesn't follow this rule.